# Remarks before notes with tabulararray

Tags: tabularray

Is there some way to have remarks printed **before** notes when using the `tabularray` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
  \begin{talltblr}[
    caption={A table},
    remark{Note}={Something noteworhty.},
    note{a}={A table footnote.}
  ]{
    colspec={@{}Xcc@{}}
  }
    \hline
    & A & B \\
    \hline
    A row heading\TblrNote{a} & a & 123 \\
    Another row heading & b & 456 \\
    Yet another row heading & c & 789 \\
    \hline
  \end{talltblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining a new theme.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    
    %*********************** addeed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytheme}{%   
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default}
    \UseTblrTemplate{note}{default} 
    }   
    \NewTblrTheme{mytheme}{
        \SetTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytheme}
    }
        
    
    \begin{talltblr}[
        caption={A table, default theme},
        remark{Note}={Something noteworhty.},
        note{a}={A table footnote.}
        ]{
            colspec={@{}Xcc@{}}
        }
        \hline
        & A & B \\
        \hline
        A row heading\TblrNote{a} & a & 123 \\
        Another row heading & b & 456 \\
        Yet another row heading & c & 789 \\
        \hline
    \end{talltblr}

\bigskip

    \begin{talltblr}[
    theme =mytheme,     
    caption={A table with a new theme},
    remark{Note}={Something noteworhty.},
    note{a}={A table footnote.} 
    ]{
        colspec={@{}Xcc@{}}
    }
    \hline
    & A & B \\
    \hline
    A row heading\TblrNote{a} & a & 123 \\
    Another row heading & b & 456 \\
    Yet another row heading & c & 789 \\
    \hline
\end{talltblr}

\end{document}
```